# SharePoint 2019： User keep signing in

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I open a site, it always automatically sign in using my account, i want to test some features on SharePoint, is there a way to sign in using a different account without having to clear browser cache?

Comment: Do you try the following answer? If you have any updates about this issue, please feel free to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the following methods to sign in a different user:
**Option 1**: You need to just append “_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true”  to your Site Absolute Url

```
URL: _layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
```

**Option 2**: Run your browser in InPrivate mode, then open your SharePoint site in this mode.

[image]